# I want to check for both negative number and non-number

Tags: java, while-loop, numbers

I have code to check for non numbers but also wish to include a check for negative numbers. If the number is negative or not a number, they have to re-enter info. I tried putting an `if(depValue < 0)....` after `try{` and before `catch` but that didn't work. It doesn't make sense to me if I were to put the if statement after the while loop.

```
String depIn = "";
BufferedReader depositInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
while(true){
     System.out.print("Amount to deposit: ");                   
     depIn = depositInput.readLine();
     double depValue = 0.00;
     try{
          depValue = Double.parseDouble(depIn);
          break;
     }
     catch(NumberFormatException ne){
          System.out.println("You did not enter a number!");
     }
}
```

Comment: Your best bet here, as almost always, is to step through the code using your debugger. If you don't know how to do that, stop what you're doing and learn how to do that. :-) It's not an optional skill, and as important as it is for programmers in their stride, it's even *more* important for beginners trying to understand what's happening.

Comment: Doesn't `if depValue < 0 { System.out.println("You entered negative number"); continue;}` work?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't understand what you're getting at? Are you saying if I step through the code I should see how to fix my problem? If so, then I have stepped through my code several times and tried different things including what I mentioned but I still can't figure it out. So I came here to see if I could get help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break out of the loop when you have the number you need.

```
double depValue;
while(true){
     System.out.print("Amount to deposit: ");                   
     depIn = depositInput.readLine();
     try {
          if ((depValue = Double.parseDouble(depIn)) > 0)
              break;
          System.out.println("The number needs to be positive!");
     } catch(NumberFormatException ne) {
          System.out.println("You did not enter a number!");
     }
}
```

Comment: I like it and I understand it. Why I didn't see this from the beginning is because of me not totally understanding the try and catch method.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the same try catch block, and just display the error message from the caught NumberFormatException

```
 try{
      depValue = Double.parseDouble(depIn);
      if (depValue < 0) throw new NumberFormatException("Negative value not acceptable!");
      break;
 }
 catch(NumberFormatException ne){
      ne.printStackTrace();
 }
```